# UISwipeGestureRecognizer on tvOS is giving me a EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, swift, tvos, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I'm trying to add gesture code for swipe up/down to my `UIViewController` in a tvOS app.

```swift
    override func loadView() {
        let swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(
            target: self,
            action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture)
        )
        swipeDown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.down
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)

        let swipeUp = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(
            target: self,
            action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture)
        )
        swipeUp.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.up
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)
    }

    @objc private func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
            switch swipeGesture.direction {
                case UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.down:
                    print("Swiped down")
                case UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.up:
                    print("Swiped up")
                default:
                    break
            }
        }
    }
```

When I run this I get a

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffee7146fe8)

on the `let swipeDown` line in the `loadView` function.

I'm using Xcode 11. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, missing super.loadView() in your code also, you should create the gestures in viewDidLoad instead loadView.

```
  override func loadView() {
    super.loadView() // ---> In this case always in the second line
    let swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(
      target: self,
      action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture)
    )
    swipeDown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.down
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)

    let swipeUp = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(
      target: self,
      action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture)
    )
    swipeUp.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.up
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)
  }

  @objc private func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
      switch swipeGesture.direction {
      case UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.down:
        print("Swiped down")
      case UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.up:
        print("Swiped up")
      default:
        break
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have overridden the wrong method:

```
override func loadView() {
```

You meant:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
```